# Why doesn't my QML property update when it is bound to Slider.value property?

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have a QML document with an `int property`, a `Slider` and a `Button` in it. I want `x` to always have the same value as `Slider.value`. Here's my QML:

```
Page {
    property int x: 1

    content: Container {
        Slider {
            fromValue: 1
            toValue: 500
            value: x
            onValueChanged: {
                console.log("Slider value is: "+value);
                console.log("x value: "+x);  
            }
        }
        Button {
            text: "Increment x"
            onClicked: {
                x=x+10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I press the Button the slider value is updated AND `x` is updated. But when I move the slider, the value of `x` is not updated. Why doesn't the value of `x` change when I move the slider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `x` is not bind to the `Slider.value`. When you bind `Slider.value` to `x`, if `x` change, `Slider.value` will also change BUT if `Slider.value` change (when you slide it), `x` value will not be change.

To solve this you can use the [alias](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/propertybinding.html#property-aliases) type

```
property alias x: slider.value // assume the Slider has a id of "slider"
```

Comment: Many thanks. It's not quite ideal because I actually want a property of type `int` rather than type `real` which is what `slider.value` is. But it's fairly easy to work around.

Comment: @donturner: What are you trying to achieve actually? If you want to change the value when a button is press (like the example above), just change the `Slider.value` directly. Alias type is mainly use for expose children's property to top level.

Comment: I am trying to use the slider to control the speed of an animation, for which I need an integer value to specify the duration of the animation in milliseconds. I can now do this in Javascript by referencing the alias and converting it to an int.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Page {
property int x: **sliderID.value**

content: Container {
    Slider {
        **id: sliderID**
        fromValue: 1
        toValue: 500
        value: x
        onValueChanged: {
            console.log("Slider value is: "+value);
            console.log("x value: "+x);  
        }
    }
    Button {
        text: "Increment x"
        onClicked: {
            x=x+10;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I established a two-way binding.

Comment: Unfortunately on beta 4 I get the error: `main.qml:4:1: QML bb::cascades::QmlPage_QML_0: Binding loop detected for property "x"`

Answer (score 1):

Use onImmediateValueChanged signal instead of onValueChanged

```
...
onImmediateValueChanged: {
    console.log("Slider value is: "+value);
    console.log("x value: "+x);  
}
...
```

Comment: When using this method it works fine when changing the slider but I get different values for `value` and `x` when the button is clicked (and I still get the "binding loop detected" message).